# how to trigger matching anchor with data attribure data-vid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several anchor link on page with same class but unique values for attribute data-vid. i want to trigger matching link which match's query string

```
<a href="youtube.com/link1" class="video" data-vid="1234"/>
<a href="youtube.com/link2" class="video" data-vid="2345"/>
<a href="youtube.com/link3" class="video" data-vid="3456"/>
<a href="youtube.com/link4" class="video" data-vid="4567"/>
```

let us assume my page url is `www.domain.com/v=2345`

i tried following code it is not working

```
    if ($(this).attr('data-vid') == '2345')
    {
      $(this).trigger('click');
      // tried also  
      // $('a[data-vid]').trigger('click');
    }
```

Comment: There is no such value => `HKg3AVKNPzU` in your l anchor link.

Comment: This is only for reference, my mistake

Comment: `<a>` tags can not be self-closed like that.

Comment: You need to share some more code, it's not clear `$(this)` refer to what?

Comment: When do you trying to invoke a click, after some user action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  triggerAnchor(1234);
});

function triggerAnchor(dataVid) {
  $('.video').filter('[data-vid="' + dataVid + '"]')[0].click();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="youtube.com/link1" class="video" data-vid="1234">a</a>
<a href="youtube.com/link2" class="video" data-vid="2345">b</a>
<a href="youtube.com/link3" class="video" data-vid="3456">c</a>
<a href="youtube.com/link4" class="video" data-vid="4567">d</a>
```

Comment: It matchs but doesnt trigger click

Comment: It triggers the click event but the provided url is not found (404 error)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Array.from($('.video')).filter(ele=>ele.getAttribute('data-vid')==='1234')[0].click()
```

demo:

```js
    Array.from($('.video')).filter(ele=>ele.getAttribute('data-vid')==='1234')[0].click()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="youtube.com/link1" class="video" data-vid="1234"/>
<a href="youtube.com/link2" class="video" data-vid="2345"/>
<a href="youtube.com/link3" class="video" data-vid="3456"/>
<a href="youtube.com/link4" class="video" data-vid="4567"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  if ($(this).attr('data-vid') == 'HKg3AVKNPzU'){
        $(this).click()
  }
```

Comment: can you tell me where is the problem, what does console returns or something? , I am not sure if you can properly access data by **attr()** maybe change it to **data('vid')** and see if then its going to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [data](http://api.jquery.com/data) methods to work with html data attribute.

To provide a solution for your problem, you can use any of the following options.

## Option 1:

```
$('a').each(function(e){
    // And relocate your path using
   // window.location.href
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

## Option 2:

```
if($(this).data('vid') !== '2345') { // Only check which is required to prevent
   e.preventDefault();
}
// Else the normal user click would be triggered.
```

If you have to check multiple prevents, then you can use [jQuery.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray) method:

```
if($.inArray($(this).data('vid'), ['123','2343','454']){
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `.data()` method https://api.jquery.com/data/

```
if ($(this).data('vid') == '2345') { ... }
```